# In org-mode, when tangling/exporting source code blocks, how do I remove the line padding that appears before/after each block?

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I have this in my org-mode file:

```
This is how we define a function:
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :tangle hello.rb
def hello
  puts 'Hello world!'
end
#+END_SRC

And this is how we call it:
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :tangle hello.rb
hello
#+END_SRC
```

However, when I use `org-babel-tangle` it appears like this in the file:

```
[blank line]
def hello
  puts 'Hello world!'
end
[blank line]
hello
[blank line]
```

How do I get it so all the blank lines do not appear?

Answer (score 3):

The way to suppress the extra blank lines that appear around the exported source code is to use [the *header argument* `padline`. Set it to `no` and it will not add blank lines.](https://orgmode.org/manual/padline.html)

With the above example, you would do this:

```
This is how we define a function:
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :padline no :tangle hello.rb
def hello
  puts 'Hello world!'
end
#+END_SRC

And this is how we call it:
#+BEGIN_SRC ruby :padline no :tangle hello.rb
hello
#+END_SRC
```

If you are within a heading, you can use the `#+PROPERTY` setting to set this up for all source code blocks within the buffer or for just the sub-heading with the following:

```
* My Section
   :PROPERTIES:
   :header-args: :padline no :tangle hello.rb
   :END
```